# MediaStore Content Provider Error (Android)

Tags: android, audio, nullpointerexception, media, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to use the MediaStore content provider to obtain all the audio files store on the SD card. I then take the title, artist, album, and add them into their respective arrays. For some reason whenever I run my code I get a nullPointerException (I will post the LogCat). Any help would be great.

Here is the code:

```
public class LoadAndSplash extends Activity {    

private ArrayList<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private ArrayList<String> albums = new ArrayList<String>(); 
private ArrayList<String> artists = new ArrayList<String>();

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);   

    Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/SALARYMA.ttf");  
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splashtitle); 
    tv.setTypeface(tf);  

    Context context = getApplicationContext(); 

    CharSequence text = "Reading Music...";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show(); 

    String[] projection = new String[] { 
            MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE,
            MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST, 
            MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM 

    };

    // Get the base URI for the People table in the Contacts content provider.
    Uri media =  MediaStore.getMediaScannerUri();

            // Make the query. 
    Cursor mediaCursor = managedQuery(media,
            projection, // Which columns to return 
            null,       // Which rows to return (all rows)
            null,       // Selection arguments (none)
            // Put the results in ascending order by name
            MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE + " ASC"); 

    if (mediaCursor.moveToFirst()) {

        String title; 
        String artist;  
        String album; 
        int titleColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_TITLE); 
        int artistColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ARTIST);
        int albumColumn = mediaCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_ALBUM); 


        do {
            // Get the field values
            title = mediaCursor.getString(titleColumn);
            artist = mediaCursor.getString(artistColumn); 
            album = mediaCursor.getString(albumColumn);

            artists.add(artist); 
            albums.add(album); 
            songs.add(title);


        } while (mediaCursor.moveToNext());


    //new MusicGetter().execute();

} 
} 
}
```

And the first few lines of the error log:

```
12-31 00:59:50.454: E/AndroidRuntime(4041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 00:59:50.454: E/AndroidRuntime(4041): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
start          activity
ComponentInfo{com.adam.mediaplayer/com.adam.mediaplayer.LoadAndSplash}:
java.lang.NullPointerException

12-31 00:59:50.454: E/AndroidRuntime(4041):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1821)
 12-31 00:59:50.454: E/AndroidRuntime(4041):    at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1842)
12-31 00:59:50.454: E/AndroidRuntime(4041):     at
android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
12-31 00:59:50.454: E/AndroidRuntime(4041):     at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1038)
```

Comment: hi, please check mediaCursor is null or not. i think you get error bcoz of mediaCursor is null.

Comment: I actually ended up using MediaStore.Audio.Media instead of just MediaStore and it ended up working fine.